# Gadfly in Julia on Mint

Tags: plot, julia

I recently installed Mint OS on my system and try to use Julia's Gadfly library. On a freshly installed Julia command line (I've installed it via the recommended repositories in Julia's documentation), I installed Gadfly by typing: `Pkg.add("Gadfly")`. Everything seemed to work.

By invoking `using Gadfly` the prompt shows the following messages:

```
Warning: could not import Base.foldl into NumericExtensions
Warning: could not import Base.foldr into NumericExtensions
Warning: could not import Base.sum! into NumericExtensions
Warning: could not import Base.maximum! into NumericExtensions
Warning: could not import Base.minimum! into NumericExtensions
Warning: could not import StatsBase.bandwidth into Stat
Warning: could not import StatsBase.kde into Stat
```

I've tried to make a plot using `plot(x=rand(10),y=rand(10))`. All I see is the is the prompt showing `Plot(...)`. My questions regarding this are:

- What does this mean?
- Did I do something wrong?
- How can I fix this?

Comment: The warnings are because Gadfly depends on the NumericExtensions package, and NumericExtensions has failed to correctly tag the version where it started to provide extensions for functions defined in the 0.3-prerelease branch. They are not harmfull, but indicates that you might run into compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the plot on a backend. For instance:

```
myplot = plot(x=rand(10),y=rand(10))
draw(PNG("myplot.png", 4inch, 3inch), myplot)
```

[This link](http://dcjones.github.io/Gadfly.jl/#drawing-to-backends) has more examples.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've read the first example, tried it and was worried because it didn't work.

Comment: @beyeran I've updated the link so that now it points directly to the section on backends.